# The size of the button on the stack

Tags: swift, uikit, uistackview

I am trying to make my own button size on the stack.
(width: 350, height: 50)

To create a button, I wrote an extension.
But for some reason it does not work out to create in the required size on the stack.

What did I miss?

```
final class ChooseLanguageView: UIView {
    
    private let ruButton = UIButton.createSystemButton(withTitle: "ru")
    private let enButton = UIButton.createSystemButton(withTitle: "en")
    private let deButton = UIButton.createSystemButton(withTitle: "de")
    
    private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [ruButton,
                                                       enButton,
                                                       deButton])
        stackView.axis = .vertical
       
        return stackView
    }()
    
    private func setupStackView() {
        addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
                stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor)
            ])
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .lightGray
        setupStackView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

// MARK: - extension

private extension UIButton {
    
    static func createSystemButton(withTitle title: String) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.frame.size = CGSize(width: 350, height: 50) // Here I am trying to adjust the size
        
        return button
    }
    
}
```

Here's what comes out:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add button width and height as constraints

```
private extension UIButton {
    
    static func createSystemButton(withTitle title: String) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ])
        return button
    }
    
}
```